# Undefined function or variable "new_m"

Tags: matlab, function, variables, undefined, call

I am new to Matlab. I have three functions. When I call co.m and pol_det.m they both work fine. However, when I call minor.m which in itself calls pol_det which in its turn calls co.m I get an error referring to the co.m: Undefined function or variable "new_m".
I am working with R2007b version. The three functions are below. Originally, they are written each in a separate .m document.

```
   function [ k ] = pol_det(a)
%calculates the determinant of a general matrix     (not just consisting of
%numbers) 
dim=size(a); %dimensions of a matrix
if dim(1)~= dim(2)
disp('Only Square Matrices, please')
end

m=length(a);
k=0;
if(m==2)
    k=sum_p(conv(a(1,1),a(2,2)),-  conv(a(2,1),a(1,2))); %calc. the determinant of a 2x2   m. 
else
    for i=1:m
        k=k+((-1)^(1+i))*conv(a(1,i),co(a,1,i));   %calc. the determinant using cofactor expansion
    end
end
if (k==0)
    disp('Matrix non-invertible')
end
end 



    function [ out ] = co( a,i,j )
%cofactor expansion,
%http://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung     /math/notes/MATH1107/wk07/07_cofactor_expansion.html
       [m,n]=size(a);
%create a new matrix by eliminating the row and column in which the %element is present
%new_m=zeros(m,n)    
row=1;
    col=1;
    for i1=1:m
        for j1=1:n
            if(i1~=i && j1~=j)
                new_m(row,col)=a(i1,j1);
                col=col+1;
            end
        end
        if(col~=1)
        row=row+1;
        end
        col=1;
    end
    %new_m
    out=pol_det(new_m);
    end



function [ m ] = minor(a)
dim=size(a); %dimensions of a matrix
if dim(1)~= dim(2)
disp('Only Square Matrices, please')
end
a=a.';
for i=1:dim(1)
    for j=1:dim(1)
        a(i,:)=[];
        a(:,j)=[];
        m(i,j)= pol_det(a);
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, given certain values of `a`, `i`, and `j`, you may never enter the conditional statement inside your loops that initializes `new_m`. In such a case, the variable won't exist when you then get to the following line `out=pol_det(new_m);`.

You should set a default value for `newm` *before* your loops and conditional statements, such as `[]`, so that the variable will always have a value. You should also make sure `pol_det` can appropriately handle this default value. Best practice is to make use of [preallocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html), both to improve performance and avoid conditional existence of necessary variables.